# How to render timestamp according to the timezone in Python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I have two datetime objects, they represent the same datetime value in different timezones. I would like to convert them to POSIX timestamp. However appearently calling `datetime.timestamp()` returns a value regardless of the timezone.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

dt = datetime(2020, 7, 26, 6, 0) 
utc_dt = pytz.utc.localize(dt) # datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 26, 6, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
bp = pytz.timezone("Europe/Budapest")
bp_dt = utc_dt.astimezone(bp)  # datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 26, 8, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Budapest' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
utc_dt.timestamp() # 1595743200.0
bp_dt.timestamp()  # 1595743200.0
```

The [documentation of `datetime.timestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) says the following:

> For aware datetime instances, the return value is computed as:
>
> `(dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)).total_seconds()`

Running `utc_dt - bp_dt` returns `datetime.timedelta(0)`. So it seems it calculates with the UTC value of the datetime objects.

I use Python in a web stack. I want the backend to deal with the timezone handling and the client to recieve the precalculated datetime values in the user's timezone in the API responses.

What is the Pythonic way to get timezone aware timestamps?

Comment: [POSIX timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) should always refer to UTC to be unambiguous - otherwise, you'd have to bind timezone information to the number - and essentially, you have `datetime` objects for that purpose. So in short, I'd say *you don't*.

Comment: @MrFuppes I understand but I don't see why I couldn't get still a _naive_ timestamp object. I want the backend to deal with the timezones and the client should just recieve the precalculated date-time values.

Comment: that's a good point but what will the client do with the timestamp? if you e.g. cast back to a datetime object in Python (`datetime.fromtimestamp()`), it will assume the timestamp refers to UTC and give you a naive datetime object that resembles UTC in the timzone setting of the client (client's local time).

Comment: @MrFuppes the client reads the timestamp and displays it according to the user's language. I want to store UTC 6:00 that the client recieves as 8:00 and displays it as 8am.

Comment: well, I would still prefer to pass the POSIX timestamp referring to UTC and localizing on the client's side ;-) Unix time is pretty prevalent, so there should be a convenient way to do this in most common languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, **I would not recommend doing this** because you can create a total mess, see my comment.

---

*Technically*, you could do it by simply replacing the `tzinfo` property of the `datetime` object with UTC. Note that I'm using `dateutil.tz` here so I can set the initial timezone directly (no localize()).

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from dateutil import tz

dt = datetime(2020, 7, 26, 6, 0, tzinfo=tz.gettz("Europe/Budapest"))
# dt.utcoffset()
# >>> datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200)

# POSIX timestamp that references to 1970-01-01 UTC:
ts_posix = dt.timestamp()

# timestamp that includes the UTC offset:
ts = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()

# ts-ts_posix
# >>> 7200.0
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to `dateutil.tz`! I didn't know that it can be also used to deal with timezones. I tried `datetime.replace()` before that you also mention but I got a wierd result with that and `pytz`. I've just read this beautiful piece now on comparing the two packages -- https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/03/pytz-fastest-footgun.html -- and it also concludes on using `dateutil.tz`.

Comment: @viam0Zah: jep, thats an insightful read! Btw, speaking of Paul Ganssle, with Pyrhon 3.9, timezone handling it will become part of the standard lib, see [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/zoneinfo.html).

Comment: I found a similar solution in Django's `timezone.make_naive()` implementation: `dt.astimezone(timezone).replace(tzinfo=None)`
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/timezone.py#L244-L251

Comment: @viam0Zah: not too familiar with that django function - does it give you a `datetime` object? if so, if you then call the `timestamp` of it, Python will assume it's local time (the timezone setting of the machine you run this on) and convert to UTC before returning the timestamp. That's why I replace the tzinfo with UTC, to circumvent that conversion.